# How to parse rss feed from website using powershell?

Tags: powershell

My data comes directly from a website . I want to be able to parse the information using powershell and using something like datagridview.
Below, am providing a sample of the data that we need parse, we just like to be able to extract the short description, date, and brief summary.

```
          Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://..../static/jf36ohodxnw7oemghsau1t7qb0w4y708.rss' -                  OutFile C:\alerts.html
         [xml]$Content = Get-Content C:\alerts.html
         $Feed = $Content.rss.channel
         ForEach ($msg in $Feed.Item){
         $ParseData = (($msg.description))
         ForEach ($Datum in $ParseData){
         If ($Datum -like "Title"){[int]$Upvote = ($Datum).split(' ') | Select-Object -First 1}#EndIf
         If ($Datum -like "comments"){[int]$Downvote = ($Datum).split(' ') |  Select-Object -First 1}#EndIf
       }#EndForEach
        [PSCustomObject]@{
       'LastUpdated' = [datetime]$msg.pubDate
       'Title' = $msg.title
       'Link' = $msg.link.InnerText
         'Comments' = $msg.description.InnerText
        'Other' = $FeedBackID
       }#EndPSCustomObject
       }
```

Comment: If this is a CSV you are downloading, simply use `Import-Csv` and `Select-Object` to get the values you need. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61129235/edit) your question and put in the first three lines of the csv data in a [formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) way

Comment: what are you doing to get the data? Please share your code?

Comment: Please, PLEASE do **not** add code inside a comment, because that becomes unreadable. Instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61129235/edit) your question and add the code in there as [formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) text.

Comment: I updated the code above. Can you please take a look? And, why the html tags are still showing, in the description area.